# Return user taxonomies

Tags: taxonomy

I am trying to return users taxonomies which where generated from using a plugin and then registering the taxonomy in the functions file.

The taxonomy generates a checkbox list in the standard user profile section to which you select the taxonomy you wish to use.

I simply canot get it to output, I am fetching everything else just fine like so for example:

```
$consultant = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')) : get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));
```

And to fetch the name I do: `echo $consultant->first_name`

I have registered this taxonomy with the name of 'Skills'

I have tried a number of methods but nothing seems to be outputting the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wp_get_object_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) once you have the `$consultant`. For example:

```
$user_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $consultant->ID, 'skills' );
```

Note that you can use the third argument to customize the term query.